# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.IO.Stream.Close()'

Tags: c#

I'm making a console application in C# where you can create and delete files. I use Stream.Close() so the user can modify a file after it's been created. If I don't the application tells me that *the process is being used by another program.*

When I try to close the stream using Stream.Close() I get this error:

*An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.IO.Stream.Close()'*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class MainProgram {
    
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n What do you want to do? \n (1) Create File \n (2) Delete File \n (3) Open File \n (4) Exit \n");
        
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if(choice == "1") {
            CreateFile();
        }
        else if(choice == "2") {
            DeleteFile();
        }
        else if(choice == "3") {
            OpenFile();
        }
        else if(choice == "4") {
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        else { 
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input..."); 
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    // CreateFile Function
    public static void CreateFile() {
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n What do you want to name the folder?");
        string folderName = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Get current directory
        string folderPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        
        // Get folder location
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "/" + folderName;
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n What do you want to name your file?");    
        string Filename = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Create Folder
        string folder = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, folderName);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        
        // Create File in folder location
        string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, Filename);
        System.IO.File.Create(file);
        
        // Close stream
        Stream.Close();
        
        // Go back
        Main(null);
    }
    
    // DeleteFile Function
    public static void DeleteFile() {
        
        // Get File Location
        Console.WriteLine("\n In what folder is the file located?");
        string fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Get File Name
        Console.WriteLine("\n What is the name of the file?");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Delete File
        string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Delete(file);

        // Close stream
        Stream.Close();
        
        // Go back
        Main(null); 
    }
    
    // OpenFile Function
    public static void OpenFile() {
        
        // Get File Location
        Console.WriteLine("\n In what folder is the file located?");
        string fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Get File Name
        Console.WriteLine("\n What is the name of the file?");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        
        string folderPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string filePath = folderPath + "\\" + fileLocation + "\\" + fileName;
        
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);

        // Close stream
        Stream.Close();
        
        // Go back
        Main(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Stream are you trying to close here? Did you open one? When you open a Stream, you close the stream object you created.

Comment: @Jimi im trying to close the stream after the user has created or deleted a file. Sorry if im explaining poorly but im new to C#.

Comment: Ignoring for a second that the Stream class doesn't have a static `Close()` method, what Stream are you referring to? What Stream do you think you opened that needs to be closed? -- Read this: [Explore object oriented programming with classes and objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/classes)

Comment: Don't ignore the return value of File.Create().  You get a stream back, that's the one you want to close.  You don't close a process, at best you'd want to wait until it is completed.  Again use the return value of Process.Start().

Comment: @Jimi If I dont close the streams and the user tries to delete a file they just created, they are going to get the error that the process is being used by another program (wich is of course this program). I thought that the solution was to close the streams, is there another/better solution?

Comment: You have to work with *instances*. When you do this: `System.IO.File.Create(file);`, this method returns a Stream object (an Instance). But you're ignoring it completely. Read the tutorial I've linked. -- This: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);` (if using .Net Framework) starts the application associated with the file type you have specified. After that, the file may (not always) be locked by the application that opened it.

Comment: Always use a `using` block on all objects that implement `IDisposable` then you don't need to think about closing them. In this case that's the result of `File.Create(file)`

Comment: @Charlieface how would I go about implementing this in my code? (Im very new to C#)

Comment: As mentioned, `File.Create` returns a `FileStream`, because most people who create files want to put something in them. So you would do `using (File.Create(file)) { // do stuff here }` In your case, you just want to create an empty file. So either do an empty `using`, or do `File.Create(file).Dispose();`. Alternatively, open the file, keep hold of the stream, then write user suppllied information and close it with  `using`